# How to get the value of variable from action class of Struts 2 to textfield of Jsp?

Tags: jsp, struts2

My action class looks like this

```
class My action class {

  public String getvariable() {
    return variable;
  }

  public void setvariable(String variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
  }

  public dosubmit(){
    variable=service.getvariable();
    return "success";
  }
}
```

By using this property tag of struts 
I am able to fetch variable's value in JSP.

But I want the value in a textfield of JSP.
How can I do that?

How to get this variables value in jsp variable in the next jsp file, so that i can manipulate this value.

Answer (score 4):

Create Getters and Setters for the variable and give the same name in the JSP. U will get the value of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value` attribute of `<s:textfield>` tag to preset value.

```
<s:textfield name="some_name" value="%{variable}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Struts UI tags, `name` attribute is used to match the Setter object when submitting the value, while `value` attribute is used to preset an arbitrary value for the object, that can (but not must) be your variable value.

This

```
<s:textfield name="variable" value="%{variable}"/>
```

means that you preset it with variable's value, and when posted, it will be set as new variable value.

Please note that your Action is syntactically wrong; 
You must use CamelCase for getters and setters (and methods, and variables names etc) like this:

```
public class MyAction class {

  private String variable;

  public String getVariable() { 
    return variable;
  }

  public void setVariable(String variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
  }

  public doSubmit(){
    variable=service.getVariable();
    return "success";
  }
}
```

or you will have problems getting values from OGNL.